# NSData to [String : AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have some legacy code I am porting to Swift 2.0 which is producing an error, where previously it had worked ok.

The error is : `Cast from 'NSData?' to unrelated type '[String : AnyObject]' always fails`

Prior to moving the code to a new project I did not receive the error and the code had worked just fine.

Code:

```
    func RestApiRequest(RestPath RestPath:String, Method:Alamofire.Method, Headers:NSDictionary?, Body:AnyObject?,ContentType:String,
    OnCompletion:(StatusCode:Int, ResponseData:NSData, inout ResponseError:NSError?) -> (Void))
{
    //Set REST url to be called
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:  NSURL(string: "\(self.baseUrl!)\(RestPath)")!)
    //Store body data if it exists
    var data:  NSData?
    //Check if body value is set
    if(Body != nil) {

        //Check if body is a dictionary
        if(Body is NSDictionary){
            //Convert to JSON
            let jsonBody = JSON(Body!)
            data = try! jsonBody.rawData()
        }
        //Check if body is an array
        else if(Body is NSArray) {
            //convert to json
            let jsonBody = JSON(Body!)
            data = try! jsonBody.rawData()
        }
        else {
            let bodyData = Body?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            data = bodyData
        }
    }

    let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
    manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = Headers as? [NSObject : AnyObject]

    manager.request(Method,mutableURLRequest, parameters: data as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .Custom({ (convertible, params) in

        let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
        if(data != nil) {
            mutableRequest.HTTPBody = data
        }

        return (mutableRequest, nil)
    })).response { (request, response, data, error) in
        var _error = error
        print(request)
        print(NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        OnCompletion(StatusCode: (response?.statusCode)!, ResponseData: data!, ResponseError: &_error)

    } 
}
```

}

Is there a way to successfully make this conversion without producing an error?

Comment: Try using a [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/), specifically, `JSONObjectWithData(_ data: NSData, options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions)`. Cast the return value to a `[String: AnyObject]`.

Comment: Perfect. That's gets rid of the error thanks ( just need to figure why the body data isn't making it to the API call now ).